# How to find someone to (once) pick up and re-send an envelope in Cancun?

Tags: usa, mexico, mail, cancun

Last week I went to a Fedex office in Cancun and sent an envelope to the US. Unfortunately a few days later I learned that the package was returned to the same Fedex office because a small amount of cash was in the envelope.

I am now in the US and cannot currently travel to Cancun to pick up the envelope. However, Fedex told me they would be able to give it to someone else if they show a power of attorney signed by me.

My question is: How can I find a trustworthy person in Cancun to (1) go to the Fedex office, (2) show them the power of attorney and obtain the envelope, (3) open the package and remove the cash, and (4) send the rest of the contents (some papers and an ID card) to me?

Of course I'd be willing to pay for this. For obvious reasons I'd prefer someone associated with a local entity as opposed to a random person off the internet. I asked a few local hotels, but no luck so far.

Comment: Not quite sure this is really travel-related... You may want to ask a lawyer or para-legal worker, or an accountant. Not sure how much the contents of the envelope matter to you nor how much you are willing to spend for this, which may limit your options. Did you ask the people at the Fedex office if they could do it for you if you provide them with said power of attorney?

Comment: Fedex was very clear that they could not do it.

Comment: My first thought when reading this was 'Why didn't you carry the items with you when you returned to the US?'. All of the answers I have come up with are suspicious in various ways. Unless you have a credible reason for doing this, any trustworthy person would likely decline to help you. In any case, I don't see how this is really a travel question, so voting to close accordingly.

Comment: I sent it via Fedex simply because it was meant to arrive before me. If this is not related to travel where does this question belong?

Comment: @Maxim I’m not sure what idea you’re expecting TSE to come up with. How did Fedex find out there was cash in the envelope and why was that a problem? If you were in Cancun, don’t you know anyone there you could ask to pick up the envelope? Is there a friend where you are now who can go to Cancun for you (the intended recipient of the envelope, if that’s not you)?

Comment: I'm guessing they X-rayed it, but not sure either. No, I was in Cancun only for a stopover of one day, so don't know anyone there nor anyone who could go there. I'm both sender and recipient.

Comment: From https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-shopping-question: There isn't much difference between "I'm currently in London; where should I eat dinner tonight?" and "I live in London; where should I eat dinner tonight?"

This makes perfect sense. But it doesn't apply here. A local could approach the problem I stated in a completely different manner.

Comment: The obvious answer is to hire a lawyer. Not going to be cheap, but should work.